# Synchronized a function call

Tags: ios, swift, synchronization

Consider a scenario, I have a function "REFRESH TOKEN", this function is called by different methods simultaneously, let's say the methods are "A", "B", "C". 
If method "A" calls "REFRESH TOKEN" firstly then methods "B" and "C" should wait until it finishes.

Does anybody have a sample swift code?

How can I attain this scenario? Appreciate your help!

```
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "serialQueue")
var myFlag = false


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.refresh(param: 1)
    self.refresh(param: 2)
    self.refresh(param: 3)

}
func refresh(param: NSInteger) -> Void {

let absolutePath = "MY SAMPLE API"
var headers: [String: String] = Dictionary<String, String>();
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"


serialQueue.sync {
    print("\nEntered ", param)
Alamofire.request(absolutePath, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseString {
    response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success:
        print("SUCCESS")
        break
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

}}

Output:

```
Entered  1
Entered  2
Entered  3
SUCCESS
SUCCESS
SUCCESS
```

I need an output like this:

```
Entered  1
SUCCESS
Entered  2
SUCCESS
Entered  3
SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 4):

- You can make use of DispatchGroup.

  ```
  let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

  dispatchGroup.enter()
  Method A { 
       //Refresh Token code here
        dispatchGroup.leave()
     }
  dispatchGroup.wait()

  dispatchGroup.enter()
  Method B { 
     //Refresh Token code here
     dispatchGroup.leave() 
  }
  dispatchGroup.wait()

  dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {

  print("Both functions are invoked one after other")

  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Request chaining is one way. If you find that you have to do this a lot then maybe look into futures and promises. Another way is to use Dispatch Group.

Request Chain example

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"]).response { (_, _, data, error) in
            if error == nil {
                Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get2\(data.something)", parameters: ["foo": "bar"]).response { (_, _, something, error) in
                fulfill(something)
               }
            } else {
                reject(error)
            }
        }
```

Dispatch Group Example:

```
 DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
  var storedError: NSError?
  let downloadGroup = DispatchGroup() 

downloadGroup.enter() 
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": 
"bar"]).response { (_, _, data, error) in
  downloadGroup.leave() 
  }
 downloadGroup.wait()
 downloadGroup.enter()
 Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": 
 "bar"]).response { (_, _, data, error) in
  downloadGroup.leave() 
  }
  downloadGroup.wait()
downloadGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
  completion?(storedError)
  }
}
```

If you want to look into Futures and Promises Alamofire made a lib
https://github.com/PromiseKit/Alamofire-

Comment: Is this a feature of PromiseKit?

Comment: Yes this is indeed

Answer (score 0):

The easy and nasty way is to set a flag and check the flag on calling the function and changing flag on returning.

A better way, as far as I found out, is using [operation queue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue).

Answer (score 0):

You should create a dispatchQueue(Serial) and put that code in sync of that queue.

```
//Create a dispatch Queue
var dispatchQueue:DispatchQueue

func refreshToken() {
    dispatchQueue.sync {
        //whatever code is there in refreshToken method
    }
}
```

Comment: I used dispatchQueue.sync, but it won't work with completion handler. I have updated my question. please go through.

Comment: Since there is any async call inside there, so you must use DispatchGroup or NSOperation Queues (Dependencies).